# What is the meaning of android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

Tags: android, android-theme, android-attributes

I'm trying to understand the line of code in the title.
I understood that **?** means that the value will be taken from the Theme.
**But** when it with prefix attrs, I understand that it is defined somewhere in the android system.
Also I saw that the selected theme in the app is a child of **Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar** that doesn't determine a value for **actionBarSize**:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>



<declare-stylable name="Theme">
<attr name="actionBarSize" format="dimension" >
        <enum name="wrap_content" value="0" />
    </attr>
```

I also find a theme (with the name Theme) at some GitHub resource that really puts a value to **actionBarSize** but this Theme doesn't seems to be a parent in any parent chain of the new android api's:
[Theme.xml](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've found, the only two attributes that `.NoActionBar` provides are:

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

The rest of the attributes are inherited from that style's parent. In the parent style chain for `.NoActionBar` is `Base.V21.Theme.AppCompat.Light`, which sets `actionBarSize`:

```
<item name="actionBarSize">?android:attr/actionBarSize</item>
```

In this case, the `?android:` prefix means that it comes directly from the Android platform, which sets it to `56dp`.

You can see all of this if you look at the quick documentation for your style:

[image]

---

All that aside, what `android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"` *means* is that the view should be the same height as the action bar. It doesn't really matter that the final value turns out to be `56dp`; the point is that, *whatever the value actually is*, this view will be that tall.

Comment: Thanks a lot but i couldn't understand your answer properly. First of all according to to code i have attached **Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar** doesn't have any parent, so how can you go up in the chain until **Base.V21.Theme.AppCompat.Light**? Secondary, i attached  **<attr name="actionBarSize" format="dimension" >** so what is **<attr name="actionBarSize" format="dimension" >** that you wrote? In addition i didn't understand what your last screenshot. Sorry :(

Comment: i only want to find the style(Theme) that set value to **actionBarSize** and **Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar** theme inherits from him. But  it seem impossible since to according the code i found (maybe is there a way to added it here), **NoActionBar** theme doesn't inherits from any theme :(

Comment: after searching million of times, i think my question should be why **NoActionBar** doesn't have a parent?

Comment: Any time a style has dots in the name, the things before the last dot are the parent (unless `parent` is specified explicitly). So the parent of `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` is `Theme.AppCompat`. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes ctrl+f for "dot notation"

Comment: `<attr name="actionBarSize" format="dimension">` is the declaration of the attribute, saying that themes are now allowed to set a `dimension` value to something named `actionBarSize`.

Comment: i have looked like crazy more than two hours (also at the url you send me) and didn't find the dot notation until you tell me :( . Thanks a lot!!!